# How to dispatch to templated call operator using SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, type-traits

I have a function that takes a templated callable argument, and passes an index to it. In some situations, I would like that index to be passed statically (I'm working with tuples). I thought this should be possible by passing a callable object with a templated call operator and using SFINAE.

At first, this looks something like:

```
struct A {
    template< size_t I >
    void operator()( int x )
    {
        cout << "A " << x << " " << I << endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    void operator()( int x, int i )
    {
        cout << "B " << x << " " << i << endl;
    }
};


template<
    typename F,
    size_t I = 0
>
inline
void
call( int x, F & fn ) {
    fn( x, I );
}


int main()
{
    A a;        
    B b;

    call( 2, b );
    call< B, 3 >( 2, b );

    call( 1, a ); // no match for call to '(A) (int&, long unsigned int)'

    return 0;
}
```

So I try to overload the call function and select the right invocation using SFINAE:

```
template<
    typename F,
    size_t I = 0
>
inline
typename std::enable_if< /* I've tried all kinds of things here */ >::type
call( int x, F & fn ) {
    fn< I >( x );
}
```

But I can't figure out the type traits to detect whether F is callable with one template parameter and an int argument. I've been referencing [this article](https://dev.krzaq.cc/post/checking-whether-a-class-has-a-member-function-with-a-given-signature/) and [this one](http://blog.quasardb.net/sfinae-hell-detecting-template-methods/) but am having trouble adapting them to my use case. Any ideas? Is it possible without modifying the call site?

Comment: Be lazy and consider tsking an integral constant as an argument to () instead of taking it as a template non type argument.  Template non type arguments passed explicitly ... well, suck.

Comment: sounds like an interesting idea, but I'm entirely clear on what the code for that actually is. Ultimately, whatever I do has to be compatible with calling `std::get`, so that's why I've been sticking with explicit template non type arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct A {
  template< std::size_t I >
  void operator()( int x, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> i ) {
    cout << "A " << x << " " << I << endl;
  }
};
```

use this instead.  Standard SFINAE tests work, no passing template nontype arguments.

In a C++14 compiler you can `std::get<i>`.  In a C++11 compiler you can `std::get<I>` or `std::get<decltype(i)::value>`.

Passing template non-type arguments sucks.  Avoid them.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a much better solution, but I still get a "no match to call" error. `long unsigned int` doesn't convert to `integral_constant< long unsigned int, I >` ? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e56d8be9bfe754f7

Comment: @ian pass an integral constant not a value.  Name the type, construct it.  `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}`.